# rails 4 : devise gem path configuration in routes.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to migrate my rails 3 application to rails 4 version.Below code in routes.rb file for devise gem works properly in rails 3 version but the same code is not working for rails 4 version.

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => 'passwords'}

  # devise_for :users, :controllers => { :invitations => 'invitations' }
  devise_for :users
  devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}

  devise_for :users do
        get "/users/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
  end
```

In rails 4 version i am getting below errror for the above code.

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action
_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:409:in `add_route': Invalid route name, already i
n use: 'new_user_session'  (ArgumentError)
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or yo
u may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming.
For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explaine
d here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
```